# Pandemic Legacy 2 - definition of "adjacent"

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

When an infection spreads, its say to all "adjacent" cities.   Does this apply to any city connected by land and sea, or just by land?

Answer (score 4):

In the [rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/38/ec/38ec25b0-821b-4c2e-b925-27c4a4038acd/pandemic_legacy_season_2_rules.pdf), page 6, it indicates (emphasis mine):

> SUPPLY LINES
>   Although there are no supply lines at the beginning
>   of the game, cities will be connected to each other
>   across land by supply lines. **Cities directly connected by
>   a supply line are adjacent.**
>
> SEA LANES & SEA ROUTES
>   Locations are connected to each other in the ocean by
>   sea lanes. **Locations directly connected by a sea lane
>   are adjacent.** A series of connected sea lanes is called
>   a sea route.

So cities connected by a (single) sea lane are adjacent, and the plague would spread to them as well.